# Material UI DataGridPro - No Rows Rendered

Tags: material-ui, playwright

I have a number of DataGrids in our app.
Running tests with Playwright - Chromium - , sometimes prevents the rows from being rendered.
As can be seen in the screenshot, the rows exist, but just not being rendered.

[image]

More details, this mostly happens when running the tests from gitlab, but I have also seen it in the front end. Just rarely.

Anybody have any idea how to fix it?
All the affected Tables have a cell that renders like this:

```
renderCell: (params: any) => (
            <div key={params.row.id} className="action_list_element">
              {params.row.actionFile
                .filter(
                  (af: ActionFile) =>
                    af?.actionFileType === ActionFileType.Output
                )
                .map((af: ActionFile, index: Number) => {
                  if (af?.file) {
                    return (
                      <div
                        className="no_line_hight"
                        key={params.row.id + index}
                      >
                        <b>
                          <FileIcon
                            fileName={af?.file.name}
                            isValid={af?.file.isValid}
                            fontSize={"small"}
                          />{" "}
                          <a
                            href={
                              "/activity/" +
                              params.row.pmxActivity.id +
                              encodeURIComponent("/" + af?.file.absolutePath) +
                              encodeURIComponent(
                                "?versionId=" + af?.file.versionId
                              )
                            }
                          >
                            {af?.file.absolutePath}
                          </a>
                        </b>{" "}
                        ({af?.file.revision}) -{" "}
                        {af?.file.isValid ? "valid" : "not valid"}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return "";
                  }
                })}
            </div>
          ),
```

Tried upgrading both Playwright and MUI to the lates version. Did not work.
Also tried to reproduce with my browser, but it went on fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seams it appeared because we were running our test with a headless browser.
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/virtualization/
The Documentation explained what was happening, and how to fix it.